# Is it possibile to export an entire Angular application as web component?

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-elements

This is a theoric question.

I know I can export an Angular component as a web component with Angular Element.

My question is: can I export and existing entire Angular Application as a web component and using it in a static website (just HTML, CSS and Javascript, no framework)? Is it technically possible?

Comment: Yes why wouldn't it ?

Comment: I don't know why; since I've never did it I don't know if the framework 'allow' that feature :)